# Play 1.2.4 : Rendering XML in template

Tags: java, xml, templates, groovy, playframework

I have recently upgraded to Play 1.2.4 and I believe the bug fix for the following ticket has had a negative impact on some of my code:

https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/57987/tickets/549-play-rest-xml-rendering-of-html-entities-issue

I believe the fix implemented above escapes all HTML entities from XML strings - including the actual XML structure itself.

So `<someXml/>` becomes `&lt;someXml/&gt;`

The problem that I am having is that I am using a template to serve XML as an API call, so the XML is returned to the caller escaped and therefore useless.

I have tried using:

```
#{verbatim} ${ anObject.someXml } #{/verbatim}
```

and:

```
${ anObject.someXml.raw() }
```

to get the XML in raw format, but this does not work.

The part of the code that is causing this issue can be found in the [groovy template](https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/master/framework/src/play/templates/GroovyTemplate.java)`__safeFaster` method (line 400).

Does anyone know of a way I can get around this new feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the question above, the the cause of the problem is in the `__safeFaster` method - or more specifically, the line:

```
if (template.name.endsWith(".xml"))
    return StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(val.toString());
```

To work around this problem we are setting the response `content-type` to `text/xml` in the respective controller and changing the template extension to `.txt`.

Hopefully the developers at Play will fix this problem in their next release.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to render an XML String, you can use the [renderXml](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/1.2.4/play/mvc/Controller.html#renderXml%28java.lang.String%29) method from play.mvc.Controller to display the formatted XML in your browser.

I tested this by adding this line to my conf/routes file:

```
# Render XML
GET    /renderXml    Application.renderXml(format:'xml')
```

Then creating this method in Application.java which reads an XML file and renders it (using [Guava I/O](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/io/package-summary.html)):

```
    public static void renderXml() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {      
    File xmlFile = new File("app/models", "xmlFile.xml");
    InputSupplier<InputStreamReader> inReader = Files.newReaderSupplier(xmlFile, Charsets.UTF_8);
    List<String> lines = CharStreams.readLines(inReader);

    String outputXml = "";

    for (String line : lines) {
        outputXml += line;
    }

    renderXml(outputXml);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I am actually using a template to build an XML file using a few objects (it is the simplest way to do it) - so I am not able to render the XML in this way.